# Embedding Inline SVG within Graphviz Node

Tags: html, svg, graphviz

Is it possible to add custom inline SVG to a graphviz node or graph?
When exported as an SVG file, the inline SVG would be part of the output graph SVG.

Answer (score 1):

No - Graphviz will not embed (inline) an SVG file into a node when SVG is the output format.  (See https://graphviz.org/docs/attrs/image/ for how to **link to** (not embed) an image in Graphviz)

Yes - An SVG file can contain nested SVG components, and SVG files are just text.  So, you can post-process the Graphviz-produced SVG file to embed the "linked-to" file yourself.  There may be programs around to do just that.  Sizing of the embedded image is probably the primary hassle.